# WordPress Login Redirect: Redirect URL adding to login URL instead of replacing it

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I've got a redirect that if someone is logged into https://yieldofdreams.live/login they get redirected to another page.

I used the following function:

```
function add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(608) ) {
        wp_redirect('yieldofdreams.live/redirect/');
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');
```

This does work, but instead of redirecting to the URL above, it instead adds to the login URL.

So that redirect takes you instead to;
https://yieldofdreams.live/login/yieldofdreams.live/redirect/

How can I make it where it completely redirects to the proper URL I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `template_redirect` instead.

```php
function bks_add_login_check()
{
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(608) ) {
        wp_redirect(home_url() . '/redirect');
        exit;
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'bks_add_login_check');
```

---

> Learn about the hook here : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/